# A conceptual question on Theory of Equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have 2 equations:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 12 \tag{1}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 -6x -2 \times 3^{1/2}y = 0 \tag{2}$$

On substituting the value of (1) in (2) we get: 
$$12 - 6x -2 \sqrt[3]{y} = 0 \tag{3}.$$

If we express $x$ in terms of $y$ we get:
$$x = 12 - 2 \sqrt[2]{y}$$

This satisfies Eqn (3) but not for (2).

How is this is a root for equation (3) but not for (2)?

Comment: are the equations $$x^2+y^2=12$$ and $$x^2+y^2-6y-2\cdot3^{1/3}y=0$$?

Comment: On substituting 1 in 2 you get Eqn 3.

Comment: Help with mathsJax is appreciated.

Comment: the second is $$x^2+y^2-6x-2\cdot 3^{1/3}y=0$$

Comment: Nope its square root of 3 not cube root of 3. Also -1 rep was not by me .

Comment: note that $$3^{1/3}$$ is the square root of $3$

Comment: thanks again for the $-1$

Comment: It wasnt from me , respected senior.

Comment: ok this can say everyone i can't Control it

Comment: Isnt (3)^1/2 the square root of 3 ?

Comment: it is $$3^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{3}$$

Comment: "Square root" = x^1/2 , "Cube root" = (x)^1/3

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have:

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+\text{y}^2=12\\
\\
x^2+\text{y}^2-6x-2\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\text{y}=0
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Notice that the second equation is a quadratic equation in $x$:

$$x^2+\text{y}^2-6x-2\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\text{y}=x^2-6x-2\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\text{y}+\text{y}^2=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$x=\frac{-\left(-6\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-6\right)^2-4\cdot1\cdot\left(-2\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\text{y}+\text{y}^2\right)}}{2\cdot1}=3\pm\sqrt{9+\text{y}\cdot\left(2\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}-\text{y}\right)}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$x^2+\text{y}^2=\left(3\pm\sqrt{9+\text{y}\cdot\left(2\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}-\text{y}\right)}\right)^2+\text{y}^2=12\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{y}\approx-1.88511\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space\text{y}\approx3.4471\tag3$$

Comment: Its Square root if 3 not  cube root of 3 . Also -1 rep wasnt from me.